# Test Should be Failing but is Not - Mocha and CasperJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, mocha.js, casperjs

I'm using [mocha-casperjs](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-casperjs)

No idea why my test is giving me a false positive here.  The html page renders aaaaa yet my test that is attempting to see if that div is rendering the text "No Companies Listed" is still passing, why?

```
"use strict";

var page = null,
    $ = require('jquery');


describe('Feature: View List of Companies', function() {
    before(function(done) {
        casper.start('http://localhost:3000');
        casper.on("remote.message", function(msg){
            this.echo("remote.msg: " + msg);
        });
        casper.on("page.error", function(pageErr){
            this.echo("page.err: " + JSON.stringify(pageErr));
        });

        casper.then(function(){
            this.page.injectJs('../../../public/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js');
        })

        done();
    });

    it('When I go to the main landing page', function () {
        casper.then(function () {
            expect(this.page).to.be.a('object');
        });
    });

    describe('Scenario 1: No Companies are Listed', function () {
        it('should see that no companies are listed', function () {
            var companyList = null;
            casper.waitForSelector('#companyList', function () {
                this.evaluate(function() {
                    companyList = $('#companyList').value;
                    console.log("list: " + companyList);
                });
                expect(companyList.to.equal('No Companies Found'));
            });
        });
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        exitPhantomJS();
    });
});


function exitPhantomJS(){
    this.exit();
}
```

And here is a view source of what is rendered:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- load Ink's CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/libs/ink-3.1.10/css/ink-flex.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/libs/ink-3.1.10/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <style>
            body {
                background: #ededed;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ink-grid vertical-space">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="panel vertical-space">
                    <div id="companyList">aaaaa</div>
                    <!--<div id="app"/>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="build/app/js/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Results

```
  Feature: View List of Companies
    ✓ When I go to the main landing page
    Scenario 1: No Companies are Listed
      ✓ should see that no companies are listed


  2 passing (12ms)
```

Comment: In the `"When I go to the main landing page'"` test you may want to return the promise (`return casper.then...`)

Comment: Are you still alive? Shouldn't you give a feedback?

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code. The most notable is that

`expect(companyList.to.equal('No Companies Found'));` would actually be `expect(null.to.equal('No Companies Found'));` and thus result in a TypeError.

You probably wanted to use `expect(companyList).to.equal('No Companies Found');`, which would not result in a TypeError and thus should give you a failed test.

The reason that the test fails is that `casper.evaluate()` provides sandboxed access to the DOM. You cannot reference variables that are define outside and if you want to get data out of it, you need to pass it out explicitly:

```
var companyList = null;
casper.waitForSelector('#companyList', function () {
    companyList = this.evaluate(function() {
        return $('#companyList')[0].innerHTML.trim();;
    });
    expect(companyList).to.equal('No Companies Found');
});
```

DIVs don't have values and a jQuery collection doesn't have a `value` property. You may want to use `textContent` or `innerHTML`.

Another problem: Since you're calling `exitPhantomJS` directly, `this` doesn't refer to `casper`, so this will lead to another TypeError. Either use `casper.run(exitPhantomJS);` or `casper.run();`.